# How to get TypeName of underlying type in in C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

I'm trying to implement the `ICustomPropertyProvider::Type()` method, however I can't find a way to get `TypeName` of a C++/WinRT type. Apparently you have `Object::GetType` and `T::typeid` in C++/CX, but not in C++/WinRT.

I tried the following code, but that was just a wild guess as it was the only thing I could find that has remotely to do with types. I presume `typeid()` has nothing to do with XAML  however, since the only guarantee it gives is that the string it returns is uniquely identifying.

```
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;

TypeName name;
name.Name = typeid(DeviceInformation).name();
name.Kind = TypeKind::Metadata;
```

Comment: `typeid()` is guaranteed to be unique; the string it returns (via `name()`) can be literally anything. Don't rely on it for anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `winrt::xaml_typename<Type>()` function template is what you're after.

Comment: I was on the previous SDK, so I thought there must be a way to do it without `xaml_typename`. But as Ryan pointed out there are some odd caveats. I'll just get the new SDK and be done with it.

Comment: Just to confirm, which SDK is this added? I'm on 17095 now, but I can't seem to find winrt::xaml_typename.

Comment: You need to include the winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h header.